# Spring roo - add JSON

Tags: spring-roo

I'm trying to learn Spring Roo. One of the thing I wanted to try is what `web mvc json setup` is doing, but I'm getting message:

```
Command 'web mvc json setup' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

which is not helping at all. I found nothing in docs.

---

Steps I did in console

```
C:\Betlista\tmp>mkdir RooJSONTest

C:\Betlista\tmp>cd RooJSONTest

C:\Betlista\tmp\RooJSONTest>roo
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
roo> project --topLevelPackage betlista.tests.roo.json --

project --topLevelPackage betlista.tests.roo.json --java           project --topLevelPackage betlista.tests.roo.json --packaging
project --topLevelPackage betlista.tests.roo.json --parent         project --topLevelPackage betlista.tests.roo.json --projectName

roo> project --topLevelPackage betlista.tests.roo.json --projectName RooJSONTest
Created ROOT\pom.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\log4j.properties
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT\applicationContext.xml
roo> web mvc setup
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\webmvc-config.xml
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
Updated ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\webmvc-config.xml
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\add.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\banner-graphic.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\create.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\delete.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\favicon.ico
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\list.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\resultset_first.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\resultset_last.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\resultset_next.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\resultset_previous.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\show.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\springsource-logo.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\update.png
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\styles
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\styles\alt.css
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\styles\standard.css
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\alt.properties
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\standard.properties
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\layouts
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\layouts\default.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\layouts\layouts.xml
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\header.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\menu.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\footer.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\views.xml
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\dataAccessFailure.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\index-template.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\index.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\resourceNotFound.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\uncaughtException.jspx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\create.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\dependency.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\find.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\list.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\show.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\update.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\checkbox.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\column.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\datetime.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\display.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\editor.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\input.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\reference.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\select.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\simple.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\table.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\form\fields\textarea.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\menu
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\menu\category.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\menu\item.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\menu\menu.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util\language.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util\load-scripts.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util\pagination.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util\panel.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util\placeholder.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tags\util\theme.tagx
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\i18n
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\i18n\messages.properties
Created ROOT\src\main\webapp\images\en.png
Updated ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\i18n\application.properties
Updated ROOT\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
Updated ROOT\pom.xml [added dependencies org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${spring.version}, org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:2.2.1.RELEASE, commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1, commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:1.2, org.glassfish.web:jstl-impl:1.2, javax.el:el-api:2.2, joda-time:joda-time:1.6, javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1, commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5; updated project type to war; added property 'tomcat.version' = '7.0.63'; added plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2; added plugin org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.4.v20120524; added dependency org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:2.2.2]
Updated SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\views\footer.jspx
roo> web mvc json setup
Command 'web mvc json setup' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following link: 
http://dodero.github.io/sosc-wmf/Configuring%20JSON%20remoting.html

They describe the issue as follows:

> ..."Due to a still unsolved issue in Spring ROO, generating JSON
>   controllers with web mvc json setup does not work anymore after
>   running once web mvc setup to generate regular web controllers..."

A clean solution would be to delete the project and start over with " project --topLevelPackage..." but this time WITHOUT running "web mvc setup".

Otherwise you might also try their suggested solution:

> "...To solve that issue, the @RooWebJson tag can be added to the
>   controller (e.g. PizzaController), and ROO will automatically generate
>   the Aspect that adds the JSON implementation..."

but it didn't work for me. Hope i could help.

Answer (score 1):

As you could check on [Spring Roo code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/blob/master/addon-web-mvc-controller/addon/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/addon/web/mvc/controller/addon/json/WebJsonOperationsImpl.java#L182), command `web mvc json setup` will be available only if a project is created and if `Spring MVC` and `JSF` features has not been installed on current project.

```
public boolean isWebJsonInstallationPossible() {
    return !projectOperations
            .isFeatureInstalledInFocusedModule(FeatureNames.MVC)
            && !projectOperations
                    .isFeatureInstalledInFocusedModule(FeatureNames.JSF)
                    && projectOperations.isFocusedProjectAvailable();
}
```

In your provided example, you are executing `web mvc setup` before to execute `web mvc json setup` so (checking code above) thats the reason of the `not found` message.

Try to execute `web mvc json setup` command instead of `web mvc setup`.

Regards,