# Command 'web mvc all --package ~.web' not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Trying to run command

```
web mvc all --package ~.web
```

from [pizza shop example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-roo-docs.pdf)
But i get error

```
Command 'web mvc all --package ~.web' not found (for assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
```

Searching 'web mvc all' on installed repositories
0 matches found with 'web mvc all' on installed repositories

I am using:
maven 3.3.9
roo 2.0.0.M2

How do I solve this

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557206/spring-roo-add-json helps

Comment: @VinayPrajapati the link provided shows an error with a found command, error here says not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Spring Roo 2.0.0.M2 is just a milestone and maybe some examples are deprecated or they have not been updated.

Controller commands have been updated on 2.0.0.M2 version, so maybe some parameters are not available.

For example, the `web mvc all` command you commented above has been updated to `web mvc controller --all`.

Also, you could use <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to autocomplete the available commands with the available parameters.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I Tink you are use mvc instead of mvn.
Please try it again.